# Android app that send the users coordinates into a database; timeout error in volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm creating an Android app that sends the user's coordinates into a database. But I get errors when I run it.
The errors I get are:

```
04-08 13:40:27.673 3036-3036/com.example.benoit.test W/System.err: com.android.volley.TimeoutError
04-08 13:40:27.674 3036-3036/com.example.benoit.test W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:122)
04-08 13:40:27.674 3036-3036/com.example.benoit.test W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:105)
```

This is the volley network call:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button emgbutton;
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2/work/wfile/test.php";

    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        emgbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emergency);
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        emgbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.bounce);

                // Use bounce interpolator with amplitude 0.2 and frequency 20
                MyBounceInterpolator interpolator = new MyBounceInterpolator(0.2, 20);
                myAnim.setInterpolator(interpolator);

                emgbutton.startAnimation(myAnim);

                GPSTracker mGPS = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
                final String ulat =String.valueOf(mGPS.getLatitude());
                final String ulong =String.valueOf(mGPS.getLongitude());

                if (mGPS.canGetLocation){
                    mGPS.getLocation();
                    /*
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ulat,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ulong,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    */

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Turn on your GPS/Location ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                StringRequest stringRequest= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                builder.setMessage(response);
                                AlertDialog alertDialog= builder.create();
                                alertDialog.show();
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not send ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                error.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> params= new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("ulat",ulat);
                        params.put("ulong",ulong);
                        return params;
                    }
                };

                MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addTorequestqueue(stringRequest);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: "There are no bugs in my code but i get errors when i run it."   

Right..

Comment: there is no code in your question. also pls format your question properly so it is more readable. this will drastically improve your chances of getting a (useful) answer

Comment: Either way, it can't connect to the endpoint in time. Make sure it is reachable and configured correctly. You can try to 1) increase timeout duration and 2) set a retry policy.

Comment: Ive asked the question again this time with the necessary code

Comment: check if your database is connecting ok and use some simple `SELECT` query to test you DB connectivity.

Comment: Can you please add code of your volley network call.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I saw you added your code as an answer. The code should be in the question, so I edited it into the question instead. You can use the "edit" link below your question to edit it further, if you want. When writing code, you can indent it by 4 spaces to get it in `code markdown`. This makes it clear to readers that it's code. Thank you for providing us with the code that causes the problem. With this informatoin, somebody should be able to help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this :

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

before

```
MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addTorequestqueue(stringRequest);
```